# Inline-block line-wrap extra space

Tags: resize, word-wrap, css

I've got an inline-block element that contains a very long word. When I resize the viewport until I reach the breakpoint of the text wrapping to the next line, I get a substantial amount of space. However, I would like the inline-block element to wrap immediately to the width of its contents.

I found it hard to explain exactly what's going on, so below an animated gif to illustrate my issue:

*Upon resizing the viewport:*

[image: animated gif for illustration purposes]

To be clear, the image above is me continuously resizing the viewport.

Does anybody know a way to achieve what I'd like? Even with CSS hyphenation the white-space still remains (which I don't want).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/527z755p/). Resize the frames to see what I mean.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I really need some code to work with.. Could you please add a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/527z755p/ Thanks :)

Comment: @AKG: I've removed my answer (it did not work if the last line was shorter than the first).

Comment: @SalmanA Too bad. While it wasn't a perfect answer, it did actually  nudge me into the right direction.

Comment: @AKG: add padding on parent element (e.g. 16px) and use left/top/right/bottom of -16px. I'll in the mean time workaround the main issue.

Comment: @SalmanA I am surprised this isn't an issue that more people have had. (or at least I haven't found them so far here on SO)

Comment: @AKG **word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-all;** it will give  output for your problem but not 100%.

Comment: Yeah ok, it was worth a try. ;) I deleted my answer as well, as it didn't work in Firefox and when the second line is longer. Sorry for the effort.

Comment: @Pzyon You don't have to say sorry for anything! Anybody who takes the time to help me out is great! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `inline-block` indeed extends on resizing as your animation shows, so that it keeps place for the long word to go into that space again.

One simple solution would be to add `text-align: justify`, but I'm afraid it may not exactly be what you want (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/527z755p/6/)).

Another one would be the use of `media queries`, as @Parody suggested, but you would have to know the dimentions of the containing `div`, and that would not be very scalable as you mentionned.

The `word-break: break-all` suggested by @yugi also works but causes the words to to collapse letter by letter, regardless of their length.

The only way to achieve the exact behavior is (as far as I know) to use javascript. For example, you would have to wrap your text into a `span` element inside the `div`, and then add something like this :

```
var paddingLeft = parseInt($('#foo').css('padding-left')),
    paddingRight = parseInt($('#foo').css('padding-left')),
    paddingTop = parseInt($('#foo').css('padding-top')),
    paddingBottom = parseInt($('#foo').css('padding-Bottom')),
    cloned = $('#foo span').clone(),
    cloned_wrap = document.createElement('div');

$(cloned_wrap).css({
    paddingLeft : paddingLeft,
    paddingRight : paddingRight,
    display : 'inline-block',
    visibility: 'hidden',
    float: 'left',
});

$(cloned_wrap).insertAfter('#foo');
cloned.appendTo(cloned_wrap);

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('#foo').css('width', cloned.width() + 1);
    $(cloned_wrap).css('margin-top',- $('#foo').height() - paddingTop - paddingBottom);
}).resize();
```

Please see the [jsfiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/527z755p/13/). (← edited many times)

That's quite a lot of code, but it works ; )

(PS : I assumed jquery was available, if not, quite the same is achievable in pure JS)

Comment: Awesome! I would have resorted to JavaScript if there was no pure CSS solution. I like jQuery but prefer not to use it if not necessary. But really, thanks man! I'll just wait a bit longer to see if there are any other cool answers :)

Comment: Thanks ;) I updated the code again for it had some unwanted behaviors when surrounded by other contents (like in real use scenario).

Comment: I did not get why you need the set the `margin-top`. In the resize function just adding `$('#foo').width(cloned.width() + 1);` works fine. I will upvote. Please explain

Comment: Try to add some element (let's say `<p>bar</p>`) after the `div` to understand why ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible only with CSS for the one element. The reason for your behavior is that the width of the element is still 100% of its container. The only way I could think to accomplish this is by doing something a little bit "creative"...try setting the style to inline so you get the shrink-wrap behavior, but to get around the background color issue, also put it in a container that shares the same background. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding you correctly you could use the `@media` type to decide what css to use depending on the width of the screen

here is an example of what i mean

```
@media(min-width:0px) and (max-width:200px){
    div {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:200px){
    div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would make sense but it is not a scalable solution. What I am really looking for is a way to naturally have the element adjust its width to its contents. Right now when it line wraps, there is always excess space on the left -- I want that gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am still very appreciative of @lapin's answer (which I accepted and awarded bounty to), I found out after the fact that it didn't quite work on multiple elements next to each other (that has nothing to do with @lapin, I just didn't mention it in my original question as I thought it would be irrelevant information).

Anyway, I've come up with the following that works for me (assuming the elements it should be applied to are `.title` and `.subtitle`):

```
$('.title, .subtitle').each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el),
        inner = $(document.createElement('span')),
        bar = $(document.createElement('span'));

    inner.addClass('inner');
    bar.addClass('bar');

    el.wrapInner(inner)
        .append(bar)
        .css({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        });
});

function shrinkWrap() {
    $('.title, .subtitle').each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el),
            inner = $('.inner', el),
            bar = $('.bar', el),
            innerWidth = inner.width();

        bar.css({
            bottom: 0,
            width: innerWidth + parseFloat(el.css('paddingLeft')) + parseFloat(el.css('paddingRight'))
        });
    });
}
shrinkWrap();

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    shrinkWrap();
});
```

Basically what I do is:

1. put the text in an inner wrap element
2. create an additional absolutely-positioned background element
3. get the width of the inline inner wrap element
4. apply said width to the background element (plus padding and whatnot)

The CSS:

```
.title, .subtitle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
    display: table;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

.title .bar, .subtitle .bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -10;
    background-color: red;
}
```