# How to force inline-block element to correctly wrap it's multiline child element?

Tags: html, css

I need to display left and right borders padded 10px away from left and right edges of the centered text. There's no problem when the all text fits into one line, but when text takes up multiple lines the wrapping inline-block element stretches to 100% of it's container width.

I need a pure CSS solution.

Here's JSFiddle with working demo of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/k8wrbctr/

Here's HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title</span></div>
<div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title that takes up multiple lines</span></div>
</div>
```

Here's CSS:

```
.container {

    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.borders-wrapper {

    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Here's the result:

```
            | The title |

|      The title that takes up      |
|           multiple lines          |
```

And here's what I want to achieve:

```
            | The title |

     | The title that takes up |
     |      multiple lines     |
```

Comment: I don't have a solution yet, I just noticed that adding a `<br>` after the word "up" causes the borders to be placed like you want them.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459929/inline-block-line-wrap-extra-space seems to be the same problem. I hope one of the solutions there works for you!

Comment: you can add something like "max-width: 80%;" for second block

Comment: Thanks @icke but the link you provided doesn't have any working solution that would be pure CSS. There is one solution that uses JS, but I really don't want to resort to that as the page I'm making is responsive so i will have to bind a listener to resize event and recalculate widths every time user resizes the window. And I really want to avoid that.

Comment: @icke: an interesting observation about <br> fixing the things, unfortunately I also can't use this as the page is responsive and words need to break differently in different resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to display left and right borders padded 10px away from left
>   and right edges

You need to give `margin`s not `padding` for that.

> when text takes up multiple lines the wrapping inline-block element
>   stretches to 100% of it's container width

That is because the content is long and the `div` will stretch as far as it can (upto parent width) to accommodate the content before it wraps to the next line.

There is another problem with your `div` being `inline-block` -  if the content is less then the next `div` will start just right after the first one and not on its own line.

**Solution** (*Keeping the `div` as `inline-block`*):

Use a pseudo-element to break the line.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.borders-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0px 10px; margin: 10px;
}
.borders-wrapper::after {
    content:"\A"; white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title</span></div>
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title that</span></div>
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title that takes up multiple lines</span></div>
</div>
```

---

***Note***:

Thanks @Kaiido for pointing it out. The pseudo-element trick won't work with its element being `inline-block`. In order for it to work, you do your padding/margin on the span, and float the `div`s. Then use `transform` trick to center it. A little more complicated.

**Example**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container {
    width: 200px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.borders-wrapper {
    float: left; clear: left;
    position: relative; left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.borders-wrapper > span {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 0px 10px; margin: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.container:after { content:''; display:block; clear: both; }
.div2 { width: 400px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title</span></div>
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title that</span></div>
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title that takes up multiple lines</span></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container div2">
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title</span></div>
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The title that</span></div>
    <div class="borders-wrapper"><span>The really long title that takes up multiple lines in a large width</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops! @Kaiido: The pseudo-element not breaking! Thanks for pointing that out... I need to check that again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kaiido. It was really helpful. I've now since updated the answer adding a fix which should work reliably across widths.

Comment: I tried both of the solutions and none of them seem to work for me. The borders still stick to the edges of the parent element, the only difference is that you put margin on .borders-wrapper element so now the borders are 10px away from the edges of their parent. But the distance between the border and the text is still not the same for single line and multiline elements.

Comment: And don't worry about the next element starting right after the first one if the content is too short. There will always be only one element in the container.

Comment: @GiedriusT: Exact padding between text and border will not happen in case of multiline. This is because of word wrapping. The extra space caused by the word which is wrapped, will add to the padding.

Comment: @GiedriusT: You can see that by setting `word-break: break-all` on the `span` as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ox8uLLsj/ But, this will cause words breaking in-between.

Comment: but if I check the element in inspector I can see that the width of inner span is not stretched because of word wrapping, it sticks to edges of the text like I want it to. It's only the parent .borders-wrapper element that gets stretched to full width of it's parent for some reason. If I use JS and manually set the width of the .borders-wrapper element to be equal to the width of the inner span element I get the desired result. I just don't want to use JS for this purpose. @Abhitalks

Comment: @GiedriusT: I don't understand really. Are you checking the fiddle that I linked in the previous comment. The inner span does NOT stick to the text edge when word wrapping is in effect. I have uploaded a screenshot based on that fiddle (removing the `word-break`) to make you understand: http://i.imgur.com/3Mf8kTg.png?1 - See the blue area which marks the text boundary. When there is word wrapping, the blue area shows the extra space. When `word-break` is used, this will not be there. Otherwise, it works perfectly fine. `padding` is exactly `10px` and `margin` is exactly `10px`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that in the last comment I was referring to my original fiddle, not the last one you posted. Try it and you will see that width of the span sticks to the text edge. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/3az0KCF.png And I really looked at all your fiddles and read all that you wrote and am very thankful that you are trying to help me to solve the problem.

Comment: @GiedriusT: Ah ok. See, your original fiddle also exhibits the same problem. When text wraps, it is occupying the entire width of the parent but the word that breaks causes the extra spacing. But, the point is that it is happening on the wrapping div, not span. And that is because we are not setting any style on the span. Only the div was being styled. My first answer was also based on the div. But it had problems with larger container and was flaky. Hence, in  my second answer, we are styling the span.